# Getting bad character range error for a python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Relevant part of the code:

```
# Get all files in subdirectories of input directory
files = []
for dir in dirs:
    if dir.endswith('.txt'):
      continue
    dir_files = glob.glob(indir + '/' + dir + '/*.txt')
    files.extend(dir_files)
```

The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deduplication.py", line 131, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "deduplication.py", line 78, in main
    dir_files = glob.glob(indir + 

'/' + dir + '/*.txt')
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 27, in glob
    return list(iglob(pathname))
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 63, in iglob
    for dirname in dirs:
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 64, in iglob
    for name in glob_in_dir(dirname, basename):
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 83, in glob1
    return fnmatch.filter(names, pattern)
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py", line 56, in filter
    _cache[pat] = re_pat = re.compile(res)
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/apps/gcc/5.2.0/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range'
```

Also, I found that the error is thrown for the directory with name "Yo[U-Turn]" and "PW3 [Epumer-Machi-Judurcha]

Comment: Can you please include the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify the exact error you're getting. I suppose if I take the code you've provided and run it on my system in an empty folder, I will get no errors (or not the error you're getting). So, there should be more information.

Comment: I have added the details now.